# Prototype 1.5 DOM loaded event

Tags: javascript, dom, prototypejs

I inherited a website that uses Prototype 1.5.1.1, and it uses `Event.observe(window, 'load', ...)` for some code that really should run as soon as the DOM is loaded, rather than the whole document. Eventually I'll either upgrade or switch frameworks, but in the meantime I'd like to fix this issue to prevent jumpy layout syndrome.

In Prototype 1.6, I would use `dom:loaded`, and in jQuery I would use `$(document).ready(...)`, but I can't find an equivalent for 1.5. A few sources mention `'contentloaded'`, but that seems to only be in Prototype 1.6's prereleases, and not 1.5 (and it's also not mentioned in my copy of Prototype's source code).

So, is there an event that's fired by Prototype 1.5 after the DOM is complete, but before images are downloaded?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to scrape up this:

http://www.clientcide.com/code-snippets/event-scripting/a-dom-ready-extension-for-prototype/

I was a big booster of Prototype when it first came out. I ended up moving to jQuery a few years ago. I resisted for a long time, but moving to jQuery was worth it.